# converting ascii values back to chars

Tags: java, char, int, ascii

ok
i have got a string that contain ascii values of numbers from 0-9 
bow i want to take that string and break it back down to its originall values

the String should look somethins like this:

52 52 54 49    - spaces are characters in the string too

i want to take the number 45 which is now built up from 2 chars 4 and 5 
i want to turn them back to their original value which is 4 but i cant figure out how

here is a sample code i tried for doing this-

```
String st = "43 54 21";
int first=st.charAt(0);
int second=st.charAt(1);
int total=first*10+second;

System.out.println((char)total);
```

Comment: Isn't 45 '-'? Regardless, you should take a look at `Scanner`. Given an int, you can just cast it to char.

Comment: it might be- i just put in there random numbers for the example-whats scanner? im being given a String not an int

Comment: figured it out -using scanner
thank you man

Answer (score 0):

```
void convertToString()
{
    char redo;
    int letter;
    int length;
    do{
    cout<< "How long is your word \n";
    cin >> length;

    cout << "Type in the letter values \n";

        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        cin >> letter;
        cout << char (letter);
    }
        cout << "\n To enter another word hit R" << endl;
        cin >> redo;
    }while (redo == 'R');

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using Scanner:

```
public String parseBytes(String s){
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
 while(scanner.hasNext()){
  char ch = (char)scanner.nextInt();
  sb.append(ch);
 }
return sb.toString();
}
```